# Mix DOM elements with Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, breadth-first-search

I am creating a tool that should be able to connect different Html elements. (See picture). The colored rectangles are Html elements, and I have to connect them with lines.

Here comes the problem, I would like to use Html even for drawing lines, but it seems that Canvas are more appropriate for that.

Is there an intermediate solution? What do you recommend?

I also have to be able to do Breadth First Search, and Depth First Search on the graph, and Html seems easier for storing Ids and such.

[image]

Comment: Use inline SVG.

Comment: Or use a canvas as background and draw the arrows on that, having the HTML on top of it.

Comment: You may find this pen by Lea Verou useful: [Trees with HTML, CSS, and a little JS](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/JpyZMO) She's not using canvas. Alternatively, SVG is a good solution.